# How to call list in aspx.cs page to .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list in my aspx.cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> emp = new List<string>();
    emp.Add("xxxx");
    emp.Add("yyy");
}
```

How can I call this list in my .aspx page?

Comment: If you mean your emp list you can't, it's a variable defined in your Page_Load scope. You can create a property for this.

Comment: It being a local variable you can't access it outside of the Page_Load method.  However you could bind it to the datasource of a ListView control or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your `emp` as `protected` or `public` in the class scope

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected List<string> emp;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    emp = new List<string>();
    emp.Add("xxxx");
    emp.Add("yyy");
  }
}
```

In .aspx

```
<% foreach(string s in emp) {%>
  <%= s %>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could show the list simply by having on your .aspx page:

```
<div id="emp_list" runat="server"></div>
```

And then in your page load code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> emp = new List<string>();
        emp.Add("xxxx");
        emp.Add("yyy");

        foreach (string item in emp)
        {
            emp_list.InnerHtml += item + ", ";
        }
    }
```

Which would show in your example: `xxxx, yyy`

If you don't want the content to repeat on postback then either set the `emp_list.InnerHtml = "";` or wrap the code in (!PostBack) check.